# No cookie stored in browser when using Passport + Express authentication

Tags: javascript, api, express, cookies, passport.js

I'm working on a web API. The flow should be as follows:

User logs in to website --> Passport authenticates the user --> Passport stores information about the user in a persistent session --> User can access the API as long as the session is valid.

Unfortunately, I can't get Passport to create the persistent session. The login part works (only valid users get through), but Passport doesn't store any information about the session in the client's browser. As a consequence of this, the user cannot access the API from this point on.

The parts of code that are relevant for the problem look as follows:

**Server.js:**

```
// call the packages we need
var express    = require('express');        // call express
var app        = express();                 // define our app using express
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');    // for accesing data from POST requests
var passport = require('passport');         // for user authentication
var flash    = require('connect-flash');    // for session management
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');// for reading cookies

// Setup the database connection
var configDB = require('./config/database.js');
var mongoose   = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(configDB.url);

// Pull schema for training
var Training = require('./models/training');

// configure app 
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser()); 


// required for passport
require('./config/passport')(passport); // pass passport for configuration

app.use(require('express-session')({
    cookie : {
    maxAge: 3600000, // see below
    secure: false
  },
    secret: 'khugugjh',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
})); // session secret
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash()); // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session

...
```

**routes.js:**

```
...

// the login route

    router.route('/login').post(
  passport.authenticate('local-login'),
  function(req, res) {
    // If this function gets called, authentication was successful.
    // `req.user` contains the authenticated user.
    console.log('logged in: ' + req.user);
  });

...
```

**passport.js:**

```
...

// the serilization and deserilization functions for Passport

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        console.log('Serialize: ' + user); 
        return done(null, user._id);
    });

    // used to deserialize the user
    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        console.log('trying to des'); 
        User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
            console.log('Deserialize: ' + user); 
            return done(err, user);
        });
    });


...
```

Comment: Are you using any front-end frameworks which are running in other port like localhost:3000 is express app and localhost:1234 is angular app

Comment: this answer might help u [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69253707/cookies-not-storing-in-browser-when-using-passport-with-express/76483351#76483351)

Answer (score 1):

One reason you may be having issues with this could have to do with the way requests are being made from the client-side. If you are using the ES6 `fetch` API, then you will have to make sure to pass in an key `credentials` to the options object with a value of `"include"`.

For example:

```
    fetch('/restricted', {
      method: 'get',
      credentials: 'include'
    });
```

This fixed the problem for me. Also, one thing to note is that you do not need the `cookie-parser` middleware if you are using `express-session` `v1.5.0`, as it comes packaged with it.

Hope that helps.

Additional resources: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch